# Skype for Business 2015 Edge server import certificate installation issue

Tags: windows, certificate, skype, skype-for-business-2016

We are installing Skype for Business server 2015 for testing purposes. I used StartSSL to get free certificate for Skype for Business Edge server. I followed the installation instructions from Jeff Schertz blog. After I imported the certificate successfully, but when I click Assign it won't see it. How should I properly install the certificate for ExternalEdge Certificate (public access) part?

Screenshots:

[image: Certificate Import]

[image: Certificate Assignment]

Comment: Could it have been imported into the wrong cert store?

Comment: Hi Todd, don't think so. I imported it to the same cert store as internal certificate.

Comment: **Find a solution** Created cert though Let's encrypt, then using Openssl created .pfx ( certificate plus key ) using the following command `openssl pkcs12 -export -out domain.name.pfx -inkey domain.name.key -in domain.name.crt` Ref:[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6307886/how-to-create-pfx-file-from-certificate-cer-pem-crt-and-private-key). Exported successfully without creating a signing request. – Jhonny S 4 mins ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue. I used a PKCS#7 Base64 encoded certificate which lead to the same issue as you saw. Then I re-downloaded it as X509 Base64 encoded and everything started to work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the certificate is not in a .pfx format or contains the wrong issued to field? Maybe the ca is not trusted? Is it a wildcard certificate? if so it shouldn't be a wildcard.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It isn't a wildcard certificate.